# VMware Fusion and Windows VM mouse scroll wheel resolution

Tags: mouse, scrolling, vmware-fusion

I have a Windows 10 instance running inside of a VMware Fusion virtual machine for the purpose of running Visio.  What I have noticed is that the rate of zoom or scroll per click is not per notch.  I generally need to click 8 times to get one change in zoom or scroll.

I verified the behavior in Edge and in Visio that scrolling one step, requires 8 notches of rolling prior to any action.   I have verified that in the native OS X environment, one notch moves one line.

I'd like to see one notch equal one zoom/scroll change inside of the VMware environment.  Any thoughts on why eight notches are required for one event in Windows?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Shut down the virtual machine
Go to Virtual Machine Library
Press Option/alt key and right-click over the VM in question

Select "Open Config File in Editor"

Add the following lines to the end of the file

```
mouse.vusb.enable = "TRUE"
mouse.vusb.useBasicMouse = "FALSE"
mks.mouse.pixelScrollSensitivity = "1"
```

Save and close the text editor.

Restart your VM.

Comment: I had the same issue with VMWare Fusion player 12.2.5 with a Fedora 37 guest. This fixed it.